# How to get list of data containing count of a field using Aggregation and Criteria in Spring Boot with MangoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

**Requirement:** documents-bookdata collection may have multiple objects with same bookPublisherName but different bookName. Means multiple books can have same publisher so need to extract count of books per publisher .

**Model class:**

```
@Document(collection = "documents-bookdata")
public class DocumentsBookdata {

    @Id
    private String bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String bookPublisherName;
//setters and getters
}
```

**Response format pojo**

```
public class PublisherBookCount {

private String bookPublisherName;
private int bookCount;
//setters and getters
}
```

**Response Format**

```
 [
 { "bookPublisherName": "docClassA", "bookCount": 3023 },
 { "bookPublisherName": "docClassB", "bookCount": 4100 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement can also be done logically ..like get the list of DocumentsBookdata using findAll and than filter it using loop and store the count for books per publisher.But that would be a lengthy approach.SO below code will simply use Aggregation to get the book cout per publisher

```
public List<PublisherBookCount> getBookCOunt(){
    List<PendingDocumentCount> list = new ArrayList<>();
    PublisherBookCount count = null;
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation( Aggregation.project("bookPublisherName").andExclude("_id"),
                                                                   Aggregation.sortByCount("bookPublisherName"));
    List<Document> docs=  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "documents-bookdata", Document.class).getMappedResults();
          for(Document doc : docs) {
          count = new PublisherBookCount();
              count.setBookPublisherName(doc.get("bookPublisherName").toString());
              count.setBookCount(Integer.parseInt(doc.get("count").toString()));
              list.add(count);
          }
          
          return list;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Utility class for **`Group by`** as below.

```
public class GroupByUtility<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Collector<T, ?, GroupByUtility<T>>
    statistics() {
        return statistics(Comparator.<T>naturalOrder());
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, GroupByUtility<T>>
    statistics(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
        return Collector.of(() -> new GroupByUtility<>(comparator),
                GroupByUtility::accept, GroupByUtility::merge);
    }

    private final Comparator<T> c;
    private T min, max;
    private long count;

    public GroupByUtility(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        c = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
    }

    public void accept(T t) {
        if (count == 0) {
            count = 1;
            min = t;
            max = t;
        } else {
            if (c.compare(min, t) > 0) min = t;
            if (c.compare(max, t) < 0) max = t;
            count++;
        }
    }

    public GroupByUtility<T> merge(GroupByUtility<T> s) {
        if (s.count > 0) {
            if (count == 0) {
                count = s.count;
                min = s.min;
                max = s.max;
            } else {
                if (c.compare(min, s.min) > 0) min = s.min;
                if (c.compare(max, s.max) < 0) max = s.max;
                count += s.count;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public T getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public T getMax() {
        return max;
    }

}
```

And from your code, call that utility class method to get **`Count,Min and Max`** by field specify as group By

```
        List<DocumentsBookdata> documentsBookdata=new ArrayList();
        Map<Long, GroupByUtility<DocumentsBookdata>> maxMap = documentsBookdata.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getBookId(),
                        GroupByUtility.statistics(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getPublisherName()))));
        return maxMap.entrySet().stream().map(obj->obj.getValue().getCount()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As i mentioned i need Aggregation approach